# Adsense matched contents - blocklist does not work

Tags: html, adsense

### Problem

- The url does not get added properly to the blocklist on "matched contents" of adsense

### Details

1. The url that I want to add to the blocklist on my "matched contents" adsense is as follows:
   https://mysnowbear.tistory.com/?page=5
2. However, when I added it to the block list, it changed into mysnowbear.tistory.com?page=5 . The slash (/) is gone!

   [image]

   3.  As such, the item appears in the "matched contents" advertisement box as shown below:
   [image]

Can anyone tell me how to add the address properly to the "blocklist", please?